# Left-justify and pad with zeros one input to the size of another input

Tags: verilog

I want to compare the size of two inputs in bits, say `N` and `x`. I would subtract the number of bits (`m = size(N) - size(x)`) and concatenate `m` zeros to the LSB of `x`. How can I work this out, using Verilog?

For example, the size of `N` is 16 bits and say `x` is `1011` (i.e., size of `x` is 4 bits). So `m` is 12 bits. The output I want to get is by concatenating 12 bits of 0's to LSB. Output would be `1011000000000000`.

Comment: One way could be `{X, {$size(N-X){1'b0}} }` . But `$size()` is not synthesizable and is a system-verilog construct. If the sizes of N, X are constants say A, B then use `{X, {A-B{1'b0}}}`

Comment: @PradyumanBissa, `$size` is certainly synthesizable as its result is treated the same as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your use of the word "*compare*" is confusing. It's sounds like you want to left-justify the assignment of `x` to `N`, padding 0's on the right. Normally Verilog right-justifies and 0-pads on the left.

There is no way of doing this readily in Verilog unless you used parameters to declare the sizes of `N` and `x` in the first place. Then you could have written:

```
reg [sizeN-1:0] N;
reg [sizex-1:0] x;
...
N = {x,{sizeN-sizex{1'b0}}};
```

If you can use SystemVerilog, it has the `$bits` system function that gives you the introspection on the vectors that Verilog does not have.

```
N = {x,{$bits(N)-$bits(x){1'b0}}};
```

It also has a streaming operator that left-justifies assignments directly

```
N = {>>{x}};
```